# jsf 1.2 two scopes in the same managed-bean

Tags: scope, jsf-1.2, managed-bean

is it possible to have the same Bean with two different scopes in JSF 1.2??
What I mean is:

```
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>beanOne</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>files.bean.BeanOne</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
    <managed-property>
            <property-name>someConfiguration</property-name>
            <value>#{configurationBean}</value>
    </managed-property>
</managed-bean>


<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>beanOne</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>files.bean.BeanOne</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
    <managed-property>
            <property-name>someParam</property-name>
            <value>#{param.value}</value>
    </managed-property>
</managed-bean>
```

Obviously, this solution doesn't work but it's what I want to do without having the same BeanOne two times with different names!
Thanks!! ;)

Comment: What is that you are trying to achieve here?

Comment: I want the same bean with two different scopes: session and request.

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible to have same bean with two different scopes. In your case, please give a different name to your other bean and have two different beans (one in `request` scope and the other in `session` scope)

To know more you can refer to some good posts by BalusC

[Link1](http://balusc.blogspot.in/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ManagedBeanScopes) & [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031885/how-to-choose-the-right-bean-scope)

Comment: ok, thanks!! finally, I've fixed my problem using this alternative: var params = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
  String someValue = params.get("someName");    so, I don't have to created another bean!! :)

Comment: In your `faces-config.xml` , what is the `scope` to which you have mapped your bean to?